# Android ViewModel reference Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-lifecycle, android-jetpack

I'm a beginner android dev and am looking to write a fully jetpack app. I'm wondering the best way to communicate with the fragment from the ViewModel to say, show a dialog, or navigate to another fragment.

I had something like this:

```
class Foo: ViewModel() {

    interface Callbacks {
        fun doSomethingWithUI()
        fun showBaz()
    }

    var callbacks: Callbacks? = null
}
```

And then in the fragments onCreate it would set itself as the viewmodels callbacks object.

Looking at the documentation it states that the ViewModel shouldn't hold onto anything related view or lifecycle, or that has a reference to the activity. Thinking on this the ViewModel is referencing the fragment that has the activity.

I'm wondering, why is this bad. Everything seems to be working correctly and if there only ever was one activity to begin with, what would we ever be leaking? Why does google make it very clear not to hold onto these things but never really says why not to.

Also, since what I am doing is not ok, what is the "correct" way for having the ViewModel tell the fragment to say, "show a dialog with this error"

Answer (score 0):

You could use Livedata with an Observer. For example you can  use a
    `Mutablelivedata<Boolean>` and attach an Observer to it.
You get the Viewmodel in the Fragment and attach an Observer to the `Mutablelivedata<Boolean>` which Shows a Dialog when the `Mutablelivedata<Boolean>` changes to `true`. An Observer is called when you attach it the first time to the Livedata and when the data changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is very broad topic and you should definitely check architecture samples from google, but in short here is the idea. Let's say you'd like to have some notification channel to report various errors. Then:

1. Under your view model, you can define `private val errorsLiveData: MutableLiveData<Exception> = MutableLiveData()`
2. Under your fragment, you can subscribe to the stream like this:

```
        myViewModel.getErrorsLiveData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            showError(it)
        })
```

3. How view model can report errors: `getErrorsLiveData().value = MyException(it)`

Answer (score 0):

You can first create the live data into two parts Mutable and Immutable. The mutable live data will be used inside the viewModel only and the Immutable one can be observed from the fragment or the activity.

```
class CarViewModel: ViewModel() {

private val repo: EngineRepo() // an instance of your repository inside ViewModel
private val _engine = MutableLiveData<List<Engines>>() //mutable live data to be used inside the viewModel
val : LiveData<List<Engines>> = _engine //this is the observable live data
```

Now,

```
fun fetchEngineDetails() {
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){

_engine.postValue(repo.getEngine()) // calling the function inside your repo

  }
}
```

Now you are done with your viewModel
So, to call this ViewModel inside your fragment let's say you can create an instance of ViewModel class.

```
class CarFragment: Fragment(){
private val carViewModel: CarViewModel by viewModels()
```

Now inside your onCreate method you can call the function using ViewModel like this:

```
varViewModel.fetchEngineDetails()
```

And inside onCreateView you can observe the livedata like this:

```
carViewModel.engine.observe {(viewlifeCycleOwner)} {
Toast.makeText(requireContext, "Number of engines is {it.size}, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()  
}
```

Please note that to use or create instance of ViewModel class inside the fragment the way I have written here you have to put some dependencies in your gradles

So in you build.gradle (Project)

```
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5"
```

and in your build.gradle(App Module)

inside plugins add:

```
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
```

and inside dependencies add :

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
```